# If $f(r)=1+\frac 12 +\frac 13+..+\frac 1r$ and $\sum_{r=1}^n (2r+1)f(r)=P(n)f(n+1)-Q(n)$, where $P$ and $Q$ are polynomial functions.

Tags: sequences-and-series, telescopic-series

If $$f(r)=1+\frac 12 +\frac 13+..+\frac 1r$$
and $$\sum_{r=1}^n (2r+1)f(r)=P(n)f(n+1)-Q(n)$$ where $P$ and $Q$ are polynomial functions,

> Prove that
>
> 1. $$\sum_{r=0} ^{10} P(r)=506$$
> 2. $$\sum_{r=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{Q(r)} = 2$$
> 3. $$P(13) -Q(13) = 91$$

For the expression inside the sigma function
$$(2r+1)(f(r))$$
$$=((r+1)^2-r^2)f(r)$$
$$=(r+1)^2 (f(r)-f(r+1))+(r+1)^2 f(r+1) -r^2f(r)$$
$$=(r+1)^2 (-\frac{1}{r+1}) + (1+\frac 12 +\frac 13...\frac 1r)(2r+1) +(r+1)^2 \frac{1}{r+1}$$
$$(2r+1)f(r)$$

This was just an attempt to solve it, as you can see I just circled back to the original function. How should I solve it?

Comment: this is your third telescoping question in under two hours. First grasp what the technique is e.g., by reading [this](https://brilliant.org/wiki/telescoping-series/). Note that this technique requires to write down term for each $r$ and then look for cancellation. Being shy of writing down the terms will get one nowhere. The topic itself will keep evading you until you pay proper attention to it.

Comment: @cosmo5 well yeah, all the sequence questions of higher order are telescoping, and I just had these three questions picked out to ask on MSE. Since I showed my working in all three of them, I don’t think it should be a problem

Comment: Ok, this time expand LHS term by term like $(2^2-1^2)f(1)+(3^2-2^2)f(2)+...$ and see what cancels. You did the difficult part by expressing terms as a difference, now you just have to wrap it up.

Comment: f(x)=1+1/2+..1/r do you mean f(r)

Comment: @cosmo5 right, I got the series $-1-2-3....-(r+1)$. How do I represent it in terms of $f(n+1)$?

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore yes

Comment: see if this helps-https://www.quora.com/If-f-r-1+-frac-1-2-+-frac-1-3-+-+-frac-1-r-and-f-0-0-then-find-sum_-r-1-n-2r+1-f-r

Comment: Are you a JEE aspirant? If yes then which year?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$f(r)=1+\frac{1}{2} +\frac{1}{3}+..+\frac{1}{r}$$ is known as Harmonic series. It is easy to see the telescoping property $$f(r+1)-f(r)=\frac{1}{r+1}$$

Proceeding from
$$
\begin{align*}
& (2^2-1^2)f(1) + (3^2-2^2)f(2) + (4^2-3^2)f(3) + \ldots + ((n+1)^2-n^2)f(n) \\
& =-1^2f(1)-2^2(f(2)-f(1))-3^2(f(4)-f(3)) + \ldots + (n+1)^2f(n) \\
& =-1^2-\frac{2^2}{2}-\frac{3^2}{3} + \ldots + (n+1)^2f(n) \\
& =(n+1)^2\color{blue}{f(n)}-(1+2+ \ldots +n) \\
& =(n+1)^2\color{blue}{(f(n+1)-\frac{1}{n+1})}-(1+2+ \ldots +n) \\
& =(n+1)^2f(n+1)-(1+2+ \ldots +(n+1)) \\
& =(n+1)^2f(n+1)-\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}
\end{align*}
$$

So we get $$P(n)=(n+1)^2$$ and $$Q(n)=\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}$$

Can you finish the rest?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you obtained $f(r+1)-f(r)=\frac{1}{r+1}$

Comment: $f(4)=1+\frac{1}{2} +\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}$. $f(3)=1+\frac{1}{2} +\frac{1}{3}$.
$f(4)-f(3)=...$

Comment: So you derived it anecdotally. Okay

Answer (score 0):

Use $2r+1=(r+1)^2-r^2$ and $f(r+1)=f(r)+\frac{1}{r+1}$, then
$$S_n=\sum_{r=1}^n (2r+1)f(r)= \sum_{r=1}^{n}[(r+1)^2f(r+1)-r^2f(r)]-\sum_{r=1}^{n} (r+1).$$ Do telescopic sum for the first part then
$$S_n=(n+1)^2f(n+1)-1-\sum_{k=2}^{n+1} k= (n+1)^2f(n+1)-\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}.$$